# Convert timestamp into datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, timestamp

I'm using a SQL Server database and I have a `datetime` column.

Now I want to convert the `timestamp` into regular `datetime` format.

```
SELECT
    [datetime]
FROM [database].[dbo].[data]

datetime
1584538200000
1584538260000
.............
1584538620000
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These look like Unix timestamps.  You can convert by adding seconds since 1970-01-01:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, [datetime] / 1000, '1970-01-01')
FROM [database].[dbo].[data]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I find that the date is not accurate,for example  timestamp 1584538200000 is converted into 2020-03-18 13:30:00.000,the accurate value should be 2020-03-18 08:30:00

Comment: @williamfaith . . . that is probably a timezone issue -- although such timestamps should be relative to 1970-01-01 UTC.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,yes I modified it and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Gordon is in general right but I think it is seconds since cdate (1970-01-01) and not milliseconds, so try

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, [datetime], '1970-01-01')
FROM [database].[dbo].[data]
```

Comment: Msg 232, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error for type int, value = 1584538200000.000000.

Completion time: 2020-03-25T22:31:56.6618446-05:00